# Slideshow is removing partial text from website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

So, after Mohamed-Yousef and Rachel's help, I managed to edit my script in a good way. Now everything works fine.  Thank you for both of you. My question was how to make a slideshow navbar. So, the code above is a code for slideshow navbar

SCRIPT

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pages = $('#container li'),
    current = 0;
  var currentPage, nextPage;

  $('#container .button').click(function() {
    currentPage = pages.eq(current);
    if ($(this).hasClass('prevButton')) {

      if (current <= 0)
        current = pages.length - 5;
      else
        current = current - 1;
    } else {
      if (current >= pages.length - 1)
        current = 0;
      else
        current = current + 5;
    }
    nextPage = pages.eq(current);
    pages.hide();
    nextPage.show();
  }).filter('.nextButton').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div class="header" id="home">

  <div class="header-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="top-menu">
        <span class="menu"> </span>
        <div id="container">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#about" class="scroll">Proiecte</a>
            <li> <a href="#trainers" class="scroll">Eustiu</a>
            <li> <a href="#testimonial" class="scroll">Altceva</a>
            <li> <a href="/login">Haisavedem</a>
            <li> <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Cecacat</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#about " class="scroll ">Prezentare</a>
              <a href="#trainers " class="scroll ">Resurse Umane</a>
              <a href="#testimonial " class="scroll ">Bacalaureat</a>
              <a href="/login ">Contacteaza-ne</a>
              <a href="# " class="dropbtn">Altele</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" class="scroll">11</a>
              <a href="#trainers" class="scroll">12</a>
              <a href="#testimonial" class="scroll">13</a>
              <a href="/login">14</a>
              <a href="#" class="dropbtn">15</a></li>

            <button class="button prevButton ">⟵</button>
            <button class="button nextButton ">⟶</button>
```

Comment: Is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ux92qd21/

Comment: Yes, but I want in a slideshow  5 uls,  and after next button new 5 uls.  (when pressed back button will appear those old 5 uls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working demo; it's a work-in-progress (cos i haven't quite figured how to set default list yet?) but i thought I'd post it anyway. The key is really to use the jquery [`.slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to cut your list up into chunks of 5.

See snippet or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/0gmcd45e/)

```js
$('#less').on('click', function() {
  prevpage = $('li:visible:first').index() - 5;
  if (prevpage >= $('li').length) {
    prevpage = 0;
  }
  $('li').hide();
  $toShow = $('li:hidden').slice(prevpage, prevpage + 5);
  $toShow.show();
});
$('#next').on('click', function() {
  thispage = $('li:visible:last').index() + 1;
  if (thispage >= $('li').length) {
    thispage = 0;
  }
  $('li').hide();
  $toShow = $('li:hidden').slice(thispage, thispage + 5);
  $toShow.show();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<button id="next">Next 5</button>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
</ul>
<button id="less">Prev 5</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the final resut is this i.imgur.com/NbUMQnn.png what is wrong? It won't click at prevbutton or nextbutton and those 678910 are already visible – i want to make my navbar to be already visible when I press next/prev button.

Comment: I can't see the pic, not on my phone anyway. If you could edit your question with the picture that would be helpful. I'm just about to have brunch. I'll look at it in an hour or so

Comment: @EminEryilmaz i said i couldn't see the picture, you didn't edit to add the picture, which was not helpful. i'm now on my laptop, and will EDIT your question with the picture. Add a fiddle with html, css and js to show how you got that output.. it looks like you're displaying inline which is not what my css said, so there's something else amiss. When you post the fiddle I can help you but in the meantime, study the parent css of the containing div/section.. this may be affecting the display

Comment: @EminEryilmaz Note: there was no jquery in your posted code. Also note the +5 /-5 adjustments to your js code (where previously you had +1/-1) Advisable that you use the  latest jquery (the latest version on SO - 2.2.1 - doesn't work)

Comment: with some part of your code, and with  Mohamed-Yousef's one, i managed to make it. Now it works perfectly. I just forgot to delete some script. Thank you for your assistance you helpmed me a lot.

Comment: @EminEryilmaz happy to hear you resolved your issue.. always good when it works out! :) Will you accept my answer then? Thanks :)